# calculating percent of a double

Tags: c#, double

I have difficulties calculating percentage of a double value. I wrote the code below but it always show "0". What can be the problem?

```
        double percent = 80; //Percent
        double toCalc = 1/1000000; //1 uAmper

        MessageBox.Show((toCalc * (percent / 100F)).ToString());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/1000000` needs to be performed as a floating point division.  I'd write it like this:

```
1.0/1000000.0
```

The way you wrote it, the division will be performed as an integer division, and then promoted to a floating point value. The integer division results in 0 which explains what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
double toCalc = 1/1000000; //1 uAmper
```

since you are assigning 0 to `toCalc`. That's why it always displays zero.

You should change it to

```
double toCalc = 1/1000000d;
```

That's because it first calculates 1/1000000 that, for integral types, evaluates to 0. Then, it is cast to double, but it's still 0.